# Why are std::vector::data and std::string::data different?

Tags: c++, standards, c++11

Vector's new method `data()` provides a const and non-const version.
However string's `data()` method only provides a const version.

I think they changed the wording about `std::string` so that the chars are now required to be contiguous (like `std::vector`).

Was `std::string::data` just missed? Or is the a good reason to only allow const access to a string's underlying characters?

note: `std::vector::data` has another nice feature, it's not undefined behavior to call `data()` on an empty vector.  Whereas `&vec.front()` is undefined behavior if it's empty.

Comment: I didn't knew `std::vector::data` returns null when the vector is empty. Why is that a nice feature?

Comment: personally I prefer to use 'empty' to check if a string or vector is empty, but that is just me.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes As you can easily supply the vector data to a function taking a pointer and coping with null pointers itself, without checking for emptiness yourself. Not an important feature, but a nice one.

Comment: @ChristianRau Wouldn't such a function take a size parameter?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Oops, that's wrong.  It's implementation defined what it returns, whereas `std::string::data` is undefined when it's empty.

Comment: Anyways, the point is moot. `std::vector::data` is not spec'd to return NULL.

Comment: @Anders: `f(v.empty() ? NULL : &v.front())` is quite a mouthful, though, compared to `f(v.data())`.

Comment: "_std::string::data is undefined when it's empty_" What?

Comment: @curiousguy, if `std::string::empty` returns true, then calling `std::string::data` evokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @deft_code I understand what you wrote. I was asking where you got the bizarre idea that "_std::string::data is undefined when it's empty_".

Comment: @curiousguy, I don't know, I was wrong.  I just read that section again (§24.2.4.3-1).  The exact value is undefined but the behavior is well defined, `[data(),data()+size())` must be a well defined range, but when `size()` is zero `data()` can be anything and be a well defined empty range.

Comment: [For the curious, I've reported this to the standards committee](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2391).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In C++98/03 there was good reason to not have a non-const `data()` due to the fact that string was often implemented as COW.  A non-const `data()` would have required a copy to be made if the refcount was greater than 1.  While possible, this was not seen as desirable in C++98/03.

In Oct. 2005 the committee voted in [LWG 464](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#464) which added the const and non-const `data()` to `vector`, and added const and non-const `at()` to `map`.  At that time, `string` had not been changed so as to outlaw COW.  But later, by C++11, a COW `string` is no longer conforming.  The `string` spec was also tightened up in C++11 such that it is required to be contiguous, and there's always a terminating null exposed by `operator[](size())`.  In C++03, the terminating null was only guaranteed by the const overload of `operator[]`.

So in short a non-const `data()` looks a lot more reasonable for a C++11 `string`.  To the best of my knowledge, it was never proposed.

**Update**

```
charT* data() noexcept;
```

was added `basic_string` in the [C++1z working draft N4582](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf) by [David Sankel's P0272R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0272r1.html) at the Jacksonville meeting in Feb. 2016.

Nice job David!

Comment: So it looks like the missing non-const data method was just forgotten.  How does one file a Defect Report against the standard?

Comment: @deft_code Indeed seems so. Another oversight may be the lack of data() in std::initializer_list, which has size() and the iterators begin/end, but not data() for template genericity with vector and string (since using &(*begin()) means deferencing a potentially invalid iterator if empty container).

Comment: In case anyone from the future finds this useful, I've asked about this on [std-discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/ll9HuEML6zo/discussion) and will submit a defect report (unless I'm told not to). Also, an alternative link for submitting issues is [here](http://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-library-issue) (it's not a massive page like the other link). Depending on how this goes, I may bring up `std::initializer_list` too.

Comment: @Cornstalks I'd like to know how it turned out, can you share some follow-up?

Comment: In C++14 (N3937) there is no change.  string still has only a const `data()`.

Comment: @Erbureth: [it's been recorded as issue 2391](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2391). Beyond that, not much has happened, unfortunately (but also understandably, as the committee obviously has a very long list of issues to review).

Comment: @Cornstalks Maybe they will incorporate it into C++17, along with contiguous iterators and similar perks

Answer (score 2):

Historically, the string data has not been const because it would prevent several common optimizations, like copy-on-write (COW). This is now, IIANM, far less common, because it behaves badly with multithreaded programs.

BTW, yes they are now required to be contiguous:

> [string.require].5: The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously. That is, for any basic_string
>   object s, the identity &*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n shall hold for all values of n such that 0 <= n < s.size().

Another reason might be to avoid code such as:

```
std::string ret;
strcpy(ret.data(), "whatthe...");
```

Or any other function that returns a preallocated char array.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Given that `std::basic_string<>`'s storage is now required to be contiguous, why wasn't a non-const overload of `std::basic_string<>::data()` added?

Comment: @rodrigo, sorry I wasn't clear.  I meant, is there a good reason to only allow const access to the character data _via the data() method_.  Thanks for the contiguous storage reference.

Comment: I don't see how a non-const `data()` is any worse for COW than, say, the existing possibility get a non-const-qualified pointer from non-const `&front()`. In both cases the implementation would have to perform the copy before returning the address -- contiguous or not, the problem for COW is that if the user can modify the element through a pointer, then the referand must be an element of that instance alone.

Comment: @SteveJessop AFAIK, basic_string doesn't have a `front()` member, so the only way to access to pointers to characters are &*iterators, `&s[x]`, `c_str()` and now `data()`. I guess that it has to be with use-cases. That is, if you use `operator[]`, you are likely to modify the string, but if you use `c_str()/data()` you are likely not to modify it. YMMV.

Comment: @rodrigo: it doesn't have `front()` in C++03, it does in C++11. I think that COW was always a fudge, since `operator[]` is supposed to return `basic_string::reference`, not some proxy type whose `operator=` does the copy. So to be conforming, it really needs to be copy-on-calling-a-non-const-function rather than waiting for the actual write. But I forget the details, it's a very hair-splitting argument.

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree. The only sensible way to support the COW is to make a difference between mutable and non-mutable strings, that is two different classes. And that's not going to happen to C++ right now

Comment: Trying to design a specification that allowed COW on a type that is also a Container (and really a variant of std::vector), leaking references to the stored objects, was really a pain, and caused major ugliness, notably the fact that the first call to non-`const` `begin()` invalidates `const_iterator`s obtained previously via `const` `begin()`. This never happens with other containers. There is a fundamental mismatch between "STL conformance" and COW.

Comment: I like the term "copy on fright" to describe the "copy on write and non-const blah blah blah". The string gets copied on write, or if you just frighten it by taking a reference or shouting "Boo!" at it. (I first heard that term used by Andy Sawyer).

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not that well-versed in the standard, it might be due to the fact that `std::string` doesn't need to contain null-terminated data, but it can and it doesn't need to contain an explicit length field, but it can. So changing the undelying data and e.g. adding a `'\0'` in the middle might get the strings length field out of sync with the actual char data and thus leave the object in an invalid state.

Comment: The spec says that `data()` and `c_str()` _"shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array."_  I thing that means they can't add a `'\0'`, but maybe that doesn't count because the `'\0'` would be outside the range [0,`size()`).

Comment: No, you *can* have embedded '\0's in a std::string, and they should work just like any other character. Don't try to `printf()` them though.

Comment: See my answer for clarification about `std::string` (not enough room here)

Answer (score 0):

@Christian Rau

From the time the original Plauger (around 1995 I think) `string` class was STL-ized by the committee (turned into a Sequence, templatified), `std::string` has always been `std::vector` plus string-related stuff (conversion from/to 0-terminated, concatenation, ...), plus some oddities, like COW that's actually "**Copy on Write and on non-`const` `begin()`/`end()`/`operator[]`**".

But ultimately a `std::string` is really a `std::vector` under another name, with a slightly different focus and intent. So:

- just like `std::vector`, `std::string` has either a size data member or both start and end data members;
- just like `std::vector`, `std::string` does not care about the value of its elements, embedded NUL or others.

`std::string` is **not** a C string with syntax sugar, utility functions and some encapsulation, just like  `std::vector<T>` is not `T[]` with syntax sugar, utility functions and some encapsulation.