# C++ string functions - Why do they often have unspecified complexity?

Tags: c++, string, time-complexity, language-lawyer

I just noticed that, according to the most recent C++ ISO standard, the `string::pop_back` and `string::erase` (to name two, there are probably others) member functions have unspecified complexity. What is the reasoning behind leaving the complexity a choice of the library coders? Are there actually any implementations of which anyone knows that have non-constant complexity for `string::pop_back`?

Comment: String interning could make `pop_back` O(N). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning . Not sure why `erase` is unspecified.

Comment: But C++11 implementations can't use string interning, since `s1.data() != s2.data()` when `&s1 != &s2`.

Comment: Anything modifying the size of the string may potentially cause its underlying storage to be moved, depending on how much has been changed. At least some versions of glibc use SSO (small string optimization) internally. While typically SSO would only be during the initialization of the string -- allowing the string to be "upgraded" to dynamic storage, there may be situations in which a string's content becomes significantly smaller than its allocated space, allowing moving to a smaller buffer.

Comment: Operations which change the string size may invoke the allocator, and the allocator's complexity is unspecified (since it is not within the library's control in general).

Comment: Just read it or try it.  If you find out that your library's implementation is not O(1) then you have a very good reason to start shopping.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, isn't the same true when changing a vector's size? `vector::pop_back` has a defined constant complexity.

Comment: `vector::pop_back` is not allowed to reallocate. "Iterators, pointers and references referring to other elements that have not been removed are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### TLDR; Because history, and that time complexities haven't been proposed yet

#### The situation:

[basic.string] only **directly** specifies that a few operations have a certain complexity:

- `size()` : O(1) since C++11
- `max_size()` : O(1) since C++11
- `shrink_to_fit()` : O(n) in C++17 (although added in C++11)
- `operator[]` : O(1) since C++11
- `swap()` : O(1)
- `data()` : O(1) since C++11

It **indirectly** specifies many more (and I'm probably missing a few here):

- `length()` : equal to `size()`
- `empty()`  : equal to `size()`
- `at()`     : equal to `operator[]`
- `front()`  : equal to `operator[]`
- `back()`   : equal to `operator[]`
- `copy()`   : O(n) (comes from its character traits)
- `assign()` : O(n) (comes from its character traits)
- `find()` and variations   : O(n) (comes from its character traits)
- `append(char* s)` : O(m) where `m` is the length of `s` (comes from its character traits)

The requirement on `data()` here is key. Before C++11, the underlying storage for a string was implementation-defined. It could have been a linked list for all that matters, so long as it could be translated into a c-style array when needed. After C++11, the underlying implementation was *still* platform dependent, but the requirement that `data()` be O(1) all but guaranteed that storage of the string was in a contiguous C-style array (no more lazily copying your linked list). In C++17, `data` was overloaded to return a non-const character array that you could modify, and such modifications would be the same as using `operator[]` to do the same, which further solidified the implementation (FWIW the storage is *still* implementation-dependent, but there's no way to satisfy the time complexity requirements otherwise).

You can see that C++03's only performance requirement was on `swap`, and this reflects the philosophy of the standard for a long time; prefer to specify only the behavior of an object and let the implementations take care of performance guarantees. This gives library implementers more flexibility to optimize for whatever they saw fit.

#### What's happened historically

When you dig into the proposals that added the complexity wordings (like [n2923: Specifying the complexity of size()](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2923.pdf)) you'll see that these complexity requirements are getting added piecemeal as people consider them.

Heck, the non-const `data()` was added in C++17 simply because it wasn't proposed before ([link to std discussion on the matter](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/ll9HuEML6zo/discussion) (really just links back to an answer our friend Howard Hinnant [posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519345/27678)))

#### Copy-On-Write

Int [n8215](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2815), the author discusses `basic_string` in detail, citing copy-on-write as one of the initial philosophies behind its design (although it didn't *quite* get there)

> On the other hand, the current specifications of basic_string are intended to allow reference counted strings for which copy-on-write (COW) is essential.

([Wikipedia, citing Scott Meyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#Copy-on-write_in_software) agrees).

If the standard was going to allow copy-on-write, it made sense to not make performance guarantees in the standard because writes to a string could either be O(1) or O(N). O(N) would be correct, I suppose, but it's a loose bound that could be misleading.

In fact, Daniel Krügler wondered the same thing as you in [LWG 876: basic_string access operations should give stronger guarantees](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#876) and also cited copy-on-write as a vestige:

> Due to earlier support for copy-on-write, we find the following unnecessary limitations for C++0x:
>   ...
>   2. Missing complexity guarantees: `data()` and `c_str()` simply return a pointer to their guts, which is guaranteed O(1). This should be spelled out.

---

So it looks like it's a mixture of allowing implementors flexibility, a discarded idea of supporting copy-on-write strings, and just a lack of people thinking about it.

Feel free to propose time complexities for basic_string functions where they are missing. The standard may be better off for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, there was the idea that you could implement `std::string` using [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).  The SGI STL even contained a [`rope` template](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) with a very `string`-like interface.

But it turned out that people used the subscript operator and the `c_str()` method a lot, more than efficient concatenation, which is why rope-based implementations of `std::string` were not competitive in practice.

Comment: Really interesting stuff. I'd love to see some of the standards discussions or proposals on the matter if you can find any.

Comment: Maybe [From Mechanism to Method: Distinctly Qualified](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/CUJ/2001/cexp1905/henney/henney.htm) is informative in this regard. But doesn't really discuss committee decision details; I expect that for middle-age C++, there is no detailed written history.