# Is the memory of boost::container::string contiguous?

Tags: c++, boost

in c++98, the memory of std::string([c++11 required it is contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518732/why-are-stdvectordata-and-stdstringdata-different)) may not a contiguous storage, what about boost::container::string?Is it promise the memory is contiguous?

If it is contiguous, it could work with the legacy api more naturally.

```
boost::container::string str("some data\0");    
old_api(&str[0]);
```

don't need to copy it to vector again

```
boost::container::string str("some data\0");
std::vector<char> buffer(str.begin(), str.end());

old_api(&str[0]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `c_str()` ?

Comment: because the legacy api ask for "char*",although the const correct type should be char const*(maybe this is due to the fact that early days c compilers do not support const)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `boost::containter::string` memory is contiguous.

And unless you use some funky allocators with non plain `reference`, `const_refeference` and `pointer` types, any `boost::container::basic_string` specialization has contiguous memory.

Look at string's `data()` method: it guarantees (unconditional) constant time and that  `data()+i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in [`0`,`size()`].